# JS - Nested i before h1 text

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I need to dinamically change this code:

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800" id="title"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullhorn"></i> Example</h1>
```

So, I have a JS function where I do:

```
h1Title = document.getElementById('title');
iTitle = document.createElement('i');
iTitle.classList.add("fas");
iTitle.classList.add("fa-fw");
iTitle.classList.add("fa-bullhorn");
h1Title.textContent = ' hello';
h1Title.appendChild(iTitle);
```

the problem is that the result is:

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800" id="title"> hello<i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullhorn"></i></h1>
```

instead of:

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800" id="title"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullhorn"></i> hello</h1>
```

So, how can I put the h1 text content before the i?

Comment: `appendChild` does what it says: **appends** a child. Maybe you want `prepend`?

Comment: Didn't know about prepend. Thanks, it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
let h1Title = document.getElementById("title");

let iTitle = document.createElement("i");
iTitle.classList.add("fas", "fa-fw", "fa-bullhorn");
h1Title.prepend(iTitle);

console.log(h1Title);
```

result will be like this in console :

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800" id="title"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullhorn"</i>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of **append** in h1Title use **prepend** on iTitle.

```js
h1Title = document.getElementById('title')
iTitle = document.createElement('i')
iTitle.classList.add('fas', 'fa-fw', 'fa-bullhorn')
h1Title.textContent = ' hello'
h1Title.prepend(iTitle)

console.log(h1Title)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800" id="title">
  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-bullhorn"></i> Example
</h1>
```